# Onbeforeunload no google chrome, alguma soluçao?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Preciso utilizar onbeforeunload para meu controle de usuarios em meu sistema, no IE esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas no chrome ele nao funciona, preciso que ao fechar o chrome ele redirecione para a pagina verifica.php que atualiz o banco de logado para deslogado, porque se o usuario fechar o chrome sem dar logout trava o login do mesmo, alguem sabe como utilizar isso no chrome atualmente?

Comment: Não é que você "Precisa de onbeforeunload". O que precisa é mudar a lógica para algo que não dependa de ação nenhuma para o login ficar liberado. Por exemplo, timeout do último acesso (mas tem muita outras técnicas). O "onbeforeunload" pode servir como recurso auxiliar para agilizar o processo de usuário que não fez o logout, mas ele vai agir em uma quantidade bem restrita de situações.

Comment: Leo como @Bacco disse, a lógica precisa mudar, a minha sugestão que já falei em diferentes respostas é o "temporizador". Principalmente pq o `beforeunload` não é e nem nunca foi para detectar fechamento de janelas, mas sim ele detecta o descarregamento da página, seja por reload, paginação ou fechamento e não existe alternativa ou função especifica para fazer isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entao, eu vou implementar o temporizador, mas não acho que seja uma alternativa 100% eficaz, porque caso o usuario feche a aba/navegador o mesmo terá que esperar x m/s para poder logar novamente, no caso capturar a açao de fechar o navegador e enviar a query de update para o banco seria perfeito pra mim por isso, caso ele feche o navegador automaticamente possa logar de novo.

Comment: @Leo é a unica eficaz se comparado ao beforeunload, ou seja de todas que tem essa é a mais eficiente, mas nada será 100% eficiente ... agora sobre esperar minutos para logar isso é ERRO NA SUA LÓGICA, a ideia do temporizador é pra deslogar, se ele abrir antes deste tempo ele já tem que estar logado e não deve precisar logar novamente, isso é outra coisa e não tem haver com o deslogar e sim com problema em como vc definiu o que é uma "sessão de usuário"... O que aconteceria se o usuário logasse em 2 pcs diferentes? ["pergunta retorica"] ...

Comment: ... Pela sua logica ele nem poderia, o que é um problema, imagine q o PC desse defeito e não ligasse mais e vc não tivesse o temporizador, ai a pessoa nem poderia logar no proximo PC, pq pela sua lógica o usuário está "travado" na sessão anterior.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ah, verdade, expressei mal minha lógica, realmente ele pode logar caso o temporizador deslogue ele por inatividade, isso resolve quase que por completo meu problema, vou implementar o temporizador e fazer o teste caso ele feche o navegador se ele se mantem logado(que no caso deve manter), no meu sistema ele não pode logar com a mesma conta em lugar algum, se der algum problema o temporizador vai desloga-lo e ele podera trabalhar em outro local, obrigado pela ajuda, me ajudou a ver o problema de outro angulo, estava pensando muita na forma que eu queria implementar.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai achar diversas respostas desencorajando essa prática, porque o usuário pode desligar o computador, faltar luz, etc. Mas eu utilizo uma solução que funciona bem para mim, pesquisa por navigator.sendBeacon para mais detalhes:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        try {
            var url = 'url.php',
                data = new FormData();

            data.append('funcao', 'executarAlgoNoServidor');
            navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
        } catch (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { funcao: 'executarAlgoNoServidor' }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Em caso de queda de energia elétrica/luz não vai resolver isto, se desligar diretamente também não. O beforeunload também não vai funcionar se o browser ocasionar um crash e fechar, ou se outro processo matar o processo do navegador.

Comment: Não entendo como essa resposta possa resolver o problema do autor da pergunta. Me parece que é só mais uma maneira de ter o mesmo bug, só que com outra técnica mais avançada (no sentido de que, qualquer uma das coisas que o autor disse que eram problema vão causar o mesmo problema na sua solução).

Comment: @Bacco Tive um problema similar ao relatado, tenho um sistema legado intranet de alguns anos atrás que utiliza esse recurso para modificar determinada informação no banco de dados para liberar algum recurso/sistema. Com a atualização do Chrome em dezembro, ele parou de funcionar, como é um sistema intranet controlável, onde todos os usuários estão acessíveis ao lado ou uma ligação telefônica por ramal, a solução acima foi usada, por ter sido rapidamente implementada e manteve o funcionamento anterior. Caso fosse algo mais complexo, gastaria algum tempo pesquisando como usar outra opção.