# Problemas de Logout com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um código para ao usuário fechar o browser, o logout ser executado.

Este é o meu arquivo de Logout.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.html");
```

Eu tentei usar um onunload (abaixo) para forçar o logout após o usuário sair da página.

```
<body onunload="logout.php">
```

Desta forma não funcionou, então tentei dessa forma (abaixo) e também não funcionou

```
<script>
function logout(){
          window.location.href ='logout.php';
      }
</script>
<body onunload="logout();">
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada em todos os comentários e na resposta desta questão e vê se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430234/onbeforeunload-no-google-chrome-alguma-solu%c3%a7ao/430238#430238

Answer (score 0):

Olá, dando uma olhada a sua questão deparei-me com o seguinte post.

Lembrando que deve deixar **retornar null**.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
   // Coloque o código aqui...
   return null;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh

Sobre a execução do seu código, uma vez fechado o navegador a sessão é destruída.

Uma *sugestão* é definir um tempo da última ação do usuário com o Id da sessão e desta forma obrigar a realizar o login novamente.